# Putting words from an input file into canonical form

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, file-io, canonical-form

I'm trying to write a code where it takes words from a text file, and puts each word in canonical order, and when run prints the original word next to its canonical form like this:

coding cdgino
games  aegms

All I have so far is this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class CanonicalWords
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        if (args.length<1)
        {
            System.out.println("You must provide an input file.");
            system.exit(0);
        }   
        String infileName = args[0];

        BufferedRead infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infileName));

        while(infile.ready())
        {
            //arraylist.add(infile.readLine())
        }

        //sort arraylist


        for (int i=0;i<arrayList.size;i++)
        {

        }

    }
    static String canonical(String word)
    {
        char[] canonicalWord = word.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(canonicalWord);
        String cWord = new String(canonicalWord);
        return cWord; 
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need clarification on anything I have writen. I do not know how to take these words to put them into canonical form.

Right now there is no real output, it doesn't even compile. I'm just very confused. If someone could help me to understand what is the basic formula (if there is one) to put words into canonical form and do what I stated above that'd be wonderful, but I understand that what I'm asking may come off as a bit confusing. Thank you.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what issue you are running into. Maybe an error. Maybe the expected output vs what you actually are getting.

Answer (score 0):

First, from the looks of this code:

> `BufferedRead infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infileName));`

should look like this:

```
BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(infileName));
```

Be careful that you fully spell out correctly; variable names and they're data types!

---

Another thing to take note of is, the method:

> `static String canonical(String word)`

isn't being called. Try accessing it in the main method.

Comment: Thank you I didn't even notice, I guess I didn't type the full word when I wrote it!

Comment: You got it, it's a fault many programmers come upon. Look at your last method, is it being called anywhere?